# Can I do nesting of #ifdef?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a requirement I need one #ifdef inside another #ifdef. Is it possible to do so:

```
Like this #ifdef ABC 
            /*code lines*/ 
            #ifdef FGH
               /*code lines*/
            #endif
            /*code lines */
          #endif
```

Is this structure allowed in c language.

Comment: One simple way to check would be to just try.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - and, one that would be quicker to try than finding the existing questions on the matter or asking yet another. 

Comment: @ajay, I tried to find, but google didn't give me that option

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, how could you answer this question by trying? With how many compilers? Since when is "it works for me" the same as "it is valid according to the standard"? If it works for him, it could still be undefined or implementation defined behaviour. Think about GCC extensions....

Comment: @Gerhardh the -pedantic flag? I just meant something as simple as this need not be asked (and most definitely will be already asked)